# How to fix 'TypeError: Buffer.from is not a function'?

Tags: node.js, typescript, buffer, ipfs

**Problem**

While trying to use ipfs-api in my application, I am getting below error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Buffer.from is not a function
    at varintEncode (vendor.js:185602)
    at Object../node_modules/is-ipfs/node_modules/multicodec/src/varint-table.js
    .....
```

My typescript file

```js
var ipfsAPI = require('ipfs-api');
....
ngOnInit() {
   this.ipfsApi = ipfsAPI(this.globals.ipfsIp, '5001');
}
```

**Reason**

The files mentioned in the error statement use '***Buffer.from***' internally.

**Version Details**

I read somewhere that it could be due to version issue and Buffer API is only available in Node v5.10.0+.

```
Buffer - 5.6.0 (latest)

Node - 10.17.0 

ipfs-api - 26.1.2
```

So I don't think version is the issue in my case.

**What I tried**

To the files throwing error, I added:

```js
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer
```

and the error moved on to next file, obviously this is not a solution and just a trial.

.

How to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I added this

```
const { Buffer } = require("node:buffer");
```

it seemed to work because the variable is now wrapped in curly braces.

previously I had this

```
const Buffer = require("node:buffer");
```

Comment: In Node.js, I use: import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array) is added in Buffer v5.10.0 [image].

Try to update Node.js version to v10.20.1. It has Buffer.from function.

Comment: I updated the version to 10.20.1, but no success. Same error.

Comment: I think, you need to update `ipfs-api` as well. It is deprecated https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-api. Its npm page advices to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client. I hope you wouldn't face any compatibility issues.